# List the current processes in C# Console

Tags: c#, list, process, console, console-application

I wanted to create a list of running in C# console,

I wrote this code:

```
var list = new List<int>(Process.GetProcesses());
```

What is proper way to make a list of current running processes in C# console ?

Comment: Process.GetProcesses *is* a list of running processes... so what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET create console-based system monitor

Comment: @blokk888 Then check Cetin Basoz answer, you'll get a list of process that you can then use to display info about each one of them ! Don't forget to mark his answer as the main answer (using the button on the left) !

Comment: Note that this list *does not automatically update*. If you want an actual monitor you would need to repeatedly call it and its fairly expensive in terms of CPU time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is that int there? Process.GetProcesses() return an array of Process. For example:

```
void Main()
{
    foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Id:{p.Id},Process: {p.ProcessName}");
    }
}
```